# HTML5 loop of a array of objects

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a grid that when clicking in a square it turns green, but i keep having trouble with adding objects to my array, if there preset they display fine but if add them once i click my mouse they wont render.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Img = {};
Img.tileMap = new Image();
Img.tileMap.src = 'TitleMap.png';

WIDTH = 1536;
HEIGHT = 896;

currentImage = [32, 32];

ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';

function createGrid() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff'
  for (var i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i * 32, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i * 32, HEIGHT);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, i * 32);
    ctx.lineTo(1536, i * 32);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}


var tiles = [{
  x: 1,
  y: 1
}];
var mousePos = null;

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: Math.round((evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) *
      canvas.width),
    y: Math.round((evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) *
      canvas.height)
  };
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
}, false);

document.body.onmousedown = function() {
  pos = {
    x: Math.floor(mousePos.x / 32),
    y: Math.floor(mousePos.y / 32),
  };

  tiles.push(pos);

}

function drawTiles() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  createGrid();
  if (tiles.length) {
    for (var id in tiles) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "#42f456";
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#42f456';
      ctx.fillRect(tiles[id].x, tiles[id].y, 32, 32);

    }
  }
}

setInterval(drawTiles(), 1000 / 30);
```

```html
<center>
  <canvas id="ctx" width="1536" height="896" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
</canvas>
</center>
```

Answer (score 3):

You were doing your `setInterval` wrong-- you want to pass the function, not call it-- otherwise whatever the function *returns* is what is passed to `setInterval`.

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">


<center><canvas id="ctx" width="1536" height="896" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
</canvas></center>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var Img = {};
    Img.tileMap = new Image();
    Img.tileMap.src = 'TitleMap.png';

    WIDTH = 1536;
    HEIGHT = 896;

    currentImage = [32,32];

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';

    function createGrid(){
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff'
        for (var i = 0 ; i < WIDTH; i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(i*32,0);
            ctx.lineTo(i*32,HEIGHT);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        for (var i = 0 ; i < HEIGHT; i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0,i*32);
            ctx.lineTo(1536,i*32);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }


    var tiles = [{x:1,y:1}];
    var mousePos = null;

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
        x: Math.round((evt.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*canvas.width),
        y: Math.round((evt.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*canvas.height)
        };
      }

     canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
      }, false);

    document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
        pos = {
            x:Math.floor(mousePos.x/32), 
            y:Math.floor(mousePos.y/32),
        };

        tiles.push(pos);

    }

    function drawTiles(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        createGrid();
        if(tiles.length){
            for (var id in tiles){
                ctx.fillStyle = "#42f456";
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#42f456';
                ctx.fillRect(tiles[id].x,tiles[id].y,32,32);

            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(drawTiles,1000/30);



</script>
</body>
```

Also, a few quick notes-- you're playing fast and loose with your `var` statements-- make sure if you don't want a variable to be global you declare it with a `var`.  And also note that `for...in` loops are for iterating over object keys-- to iterate over an array, use a standard `for` loop.  And finally, consider if a `setInterval` is even required-- seems like it might be sufficient to simply call `drawTiles` in the `onmousedown` after you push the new position into the `tiles` array.

Comment: Also, the mouse position is off, shouldn't it be `ctx.fillRect(tiles[id].x*32,tiles[id].y*32,32,32);`? Or just remove the `/32` from mousedown

Comment: @Corvae -- yeah, good point, I definitely noticed that things weren't positioning how I would expect-- but I had to stop somewhere :)